# jqGrid stype select empty on search dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm using version 4.1.1 and I'm configuring a column to be filtered using a .
The part that matters looks like this

```
..., stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], dataUrl: 'myUrl', buildSelect: myFunctionName }
```

Everything works great on the grid but not on the advanced search dialog.
There the  appears empty, without any options to choose from.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this one was tricky...

Apparently jqGrid executes the request differently when populating the comboboxes on the grid header and on the search dialog.

I'm pulling the data from a ASP.net ASHX and when the request is made from the grid the result is the http response object. On the other hand, when the request is made from the dialog the result is the (expected) json string.

To solve this quickly I used this:

```
var list = typeof data === "string" ? eval(data) : eval(data.responseText);
```

So, if the result is a string I parse it directly to json, if it's an object I have to go deeper to get my json from the responseText.

I don't like it... but works :)